# How do you access Dijit elements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dojo

For example, say I need to trigger an alert on dijitButton .hover() but how do I actually access that button? Everything I do comes up blank, including giving the button an ID or trying to do .dijitButton, .dijitButtonNode, etc.

How do you access Dijit elements in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dijit.byId("mybuttonId")._cssMouseEvent({type:"mouseover"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple: you don't. Dojo objects are not jQuery objects an they don't share the same methods. You can't call `jQuery.hover()` on a Dojo object unless you use its ID and create a jQuery object from it. Otherwise, you need to use a Dojo equivalent.

[EDIT]

I've just noticed you already tried passing jQuery the button's ID. My guess is it doesn't work because at the time jQuery code executes, the button hasn't been yet created by Dojo.